# What is the effect of having empty tables in your database?

Tags: ms-access

I have a few temporary tables that I use for a second, then clear out the data. Should I delete these tables after I finish using them or would it be okay to leave them?

Comment: hello and welcome to SO; please read the answers on this post as it might solve your question: [Unused Tables Database Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522295/unused-database-table-effects)

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to leave them.

You may wish from time to time to check the file size and run a Compact & Repair.